# Apache Cordova Facebook Plugin login not alerting details (not logging in?)

Tags: facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm using cordova phonegap and the phonegap-facebook-plugin to login people to my app using facebook.  When I use [this documentation](http://www.phonegaptutorial.com/integrate-facebook-into-your-phonegap-app/) I don't get what I think should be the expected behavior.

What I'm doing:
I add to my ondevicereadyevent this code:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', initApp, false);

// facebookConnectPlugin.login(Array strings of permissions, Function success, Function failure)

var fbLoginSuccess = function (userData) 
{
    alert("UserInfo: " + JSON.stringify(userData));
}

function initApp()
{
    facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile"],
        fbLoginSuccess,
        function (error) { alert("" + error) }
    );
}
```

But, when I do that and I launch the app on my iPhone, it displays no alerts or prompts to login to facebook.

Also, I tried using [this documentation](https://github.com/wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin)

I add the following code to my ondevicereadyevent

```
var fbLoginSuccess = function (userData) {
    alert("UserInfo: " + JSON.stringify(userData));
}

facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile"],
    fbLoginSuccess,
    function (error) { alert("" + error) }
);
```

But again, when I launch the app, there are no alerts or prompts to login to facebook.

When I add alerts as below, only hello1, hello2, and hello2.1 pop up

```
    onDeviceReady: function() {
alert("hello1");
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        var response;
alert("hello2");
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', initApp, false);

alert("hello3");
// facebookConnectPlugin.login(Array strings of permissions, Function success, Function failure)
var fbLoginSuccess = function (userData) 
{
    alert("UserInfo: " + JSON.stringify(userData));
    facebookConnectPlugin.getAccessToken(function(token) 
    {
        alert("Token: " + token);
    }, function(err) {
        alert("Could not get access token: " + err);
    });
}
alert("hello4");
facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile"],
    fbLoginSuccess,
    function (error) { alert("" + error) }
);
alert("hello5");

function initApp()
{
    alert("hello2.1");
    facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile"],
        fbLoginSuccess,
        function (error) { alert("" + error) }
    );
    alert("hello2.2");
}
    },
```

Comment: What's your development environment (OS, PHP version, IDE, etc)? And do you have error reporting turned on?

Comment: I'm developing in Windows 10, using notepad++ to edit the javascript, css, and html files

Comment: And if you make a syntax error in server-side code, does it show you the error?

Comment: I don't have server side code written yet.  I thought the code above should work on the phone without having to build anything out on a server yet?

Comment: How do you know for sure if your libraries are correctly getting loaded? Have you tried just outputting some message on a basic event?

Comment: When I add alert("hello") to my ondevicereadyevent, it pops up as expected.

Comment: Please add that bit of code with the alert to the question.

Comment: Let's not make this a chat session. I don't want you to include that comment. Rather I want you to include the **block of code with the alert** so that I may verify if you're trying it correctly. Include a function or something from the framework to make sure. Just the alert line in plain javascript is not the same as including it within a function of the library.

Answer (score 0):

Some points:

Before you install a plugin, read the official documentation, read the blogpost and read the issues on github.

The most plugins are third party. That means, it is possible that they don't work, a lot of them are old, …

If you read the official blogpost from Cordova here:

http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/12/08/cordova-ios-4.0.0.html

and you read the issues for your plugin here:

https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/issues/1199

Then you now, that the plugin will not work on Cordova versions newer then 8. of dec. 2015

What you can do is: Install an older version of cordova, that means in your case, something lower then 4. How to do it, you can read here:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/platform_plugin_versioning_ref/index.html